# Is it possible to see private file/class names of framework in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, shared-libraries

I have got a framework from a vendor and it crashes intermittently. I identified the class name and method which causes the crash but it is not visible when I open header folder of framework. Is it possible to check whether that class is used inside framework as private file or not?
Is there any terminal script which I run in .framework file and list all class names/files names of framework?
Appreciate your response.